# Weird mongoose behavior when viewing ObjectIds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When viewing a sub-document with Robomongo I see something like this:

```
"views" : [ 
    ObjectId("53a478431275cf0f3d91e27d"), 
    ObjectId("53a478431275cf0f3d91e27d")
]
```

But when I pull down the object through Mongoose into node.js, I see something like this:

```
views:
[ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
   id: 'T\u001aôj#Ü«m¢©Ö',
   viewDate: '2015-07-07T23:21:32.259Z' } ]
```

Yes, the schema is a little different, and I'm trying to write a script to remediate the data into the new format.

The schema is currently

```
    views: [{view:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users'},viewDate:{type: Date, default: Date.now}}],
```

But
A) Why does the view object look all messed up in the latter, and
B) How can I get what I see in Robomongo? (Answered. See edit)

---

**EDIT:** Question B is answered. If I do `.lean()` to my query, then I'll be able to get it back as a non-mongoose object and it'll look how I expect it to look. So that just leaves question A

Comment: Can you include your schema def for `views`?

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the Mongoose result?

Comment: @robertklep I'm just doing `console.log(document)` after doing a `Model.find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this.

- First, you declared a schema similar to this:

  ```
  views : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'users' }
  ```

  You created and wrote documents to the database using that schema.
- Then you changed the schema to your current:

  ```
  views: [{
    view     : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    viewDate : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }]
  ```

  Using that schema, you are reading the documents that you wrote to the database using the first schema.

Those schema are fundamentally different: the first is stored as a single `ObjectId` in the database (the term *"subdocument"* is a bit confusing, because in Mongoose, subdocuments are documents that are stored with their parent document; the method you're using is called "population" in Mongoose-speak), but the second schema makes `views` an *array* of documents that have two properties (`view`, which is stored as an `ObjectId` and `viewData` which is a date).

This confuses Mongoose because it tries to apply the second schema to documents that were written using the first schema, and because of that, it's showing the internal representation of an `ObjectId` object instead of a stringified version of it.

This also explains why `.lean()` shows the correct results, because that tells Mongoose to return raw documents (as they are stored in the database) instead of trying to convert them according to the schema.